# Python Subprocess : Send a sequence of commands to a process depending on the output of the previous command

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to execute a sequence of commands with the program [xfoil](https://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/xfoil/).

I've got to the point of getting all the commands I'm sending so that it can be directly loaded without control to xfoil with input redirection ex : "xfoil < inputfile"

```
load sd7032.dat   
oper  
iter 100   
type 2  
visc 100000  
alfa 0.0  
dump target_sd7032_alfa_0.0_Re_100000_Type2.dmp
```

With subprocess or some other means, is there a way for me to send one command at a time, such that the output of the first load command is checked before sending the second?

preferably with something similar to:

```
ps = sp.Popen(['xfoil.exe'], stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
for command in commdand_list:
    ps.stdin.write(cmd+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
import subprocess
for command in command_list:
    res = subprocess.run(f'xfoil {command}', shell=True, capture_output=True)
    print(f"return code is: {res.returncode}")
    print(f"stdout is: {res.stdout}")
    print(f"stderr is: {res.stderr}")
```

if you want to fail the loop if a specific command failed, you can add `check=True` as a parameter to `subprocess.run(...,check=True)` function.

In addition, if `xfoil` is runnable only from specific directory, you can `cwd="path/to/run"` to `subprocess.run()`.

Comment: Hi Gabip, Sorry this doesnt work as it creates a new xfoil process on each command. With XFOIL thats not the case. when you run xfoil its one process on which you can type your commands in (in other words it has its own command set and  that is what i am trying to execute one by one) similar to a ftp connection for example